# Using quote with a list in a function

Tags: clojure

I must be misunderstanding something about how to define functions. I'm doing this SICP exercise, "Define a procedure that takes three numbers as arguments and returns the sum of the squares of the two larger numbers."

I try this in the REPL, and it seems to work:

```
=> (reduce + (map (fn [x] (* x x)) (rest (sort '(2 1 0)))))
5
```

But defining a procedure and replacing the numbers with parameters gives me an error:

```
=> (defn my-procedure [a b c] (reduce + (map (fn [x] (* x x)) (rest (sort '(a b c))))))
ClassCastException clojure.lang.Symbol cannot be cast to java.lang.Number clojure.lang.Numbers.multiply (Numbers.java:146)
```

What am I not seeing? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
(defn my-procedure [a b c]
  (reduce + (map (fn [x] (* x x)) (rest (sort (list a b c))))))
```

here is why:

When you use a [quote form](http://clojure.org/special_forms#Special%20Forms--%28quote%20form%29), the form is not evaluated and your vars are not resolved. You are left with a list of symbols in your case.

```
user=> (def a 1)
#'user/a
user=> '(a)
(a)
user=> (list a)
(1)
user=> `(a) ;; backtick causes vars to be namespace qualified
(user/a)
user=> (class (first '(a)))
clojure.lang.Symbol
```

Rather than create an un-evaluated form, you should use the `list` function or another collection

```
user=> [a] ;; vector
[1]
user=> #{a} ;; set
#{1}

;; (defn sum-of-squares [& args]
;;   (apply + (map #(* % %) args)))
```

Comment: So if I understand you right: I thought that quote forms were to keep the first element of a list from being considered as an operator; but it actually prevents ALL evaluation, so I get symbols instead of the values I've bound them to. Thanks!

Comment: @tom - in Clojure, you'd normally use a vector (`[a b c`]) in that situation. I barely ever use lists outside of macros.

Comment: I'd also add that there's the `macroexpand-1` function to find out what the reader macros expand to. It'd also be worth reading [The Reader](http://clojure.org/reader) in the Clojure documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Automatically putting the function's arguments in a collection:

```
(defn foo [& x]
  (reduce + (map #(* % %) (rest (sort x)))))
```